# JSAjaxFileUploader show image after upload

Tags: javascript, ajax, file, upload, jsajaxfileuploader

I am using [JSAjaxFileUploader](https://github.com/JSEver/JSAjaxFileUploader) but cant find any option to show the thumbnail after file uploaded as it automatically slide out.

There is no option for this in documentation either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no such functionality in plugin we will have to edit the core plugin file.

In JSAjaxFileUploader.js file find this line:

```
$eml.slideUp(settings.closeAnimationSpeed,function(){$eml.remove();});
```

Remove this line and instead add the following:

```
$('.JSOprIcons img[title="Stop Upload"]', $eml).remove();
$('.JSpercent', $eml).html('Uploaded');
$('.JSProgressBarParent', $eml).remove();
var thisFileSize = $('.JSsize', $eml).html();
var thisFileSizeShort = thisFileSize.substr(0, thisFileSize.indexOf('/'));
$('.JSsize', $eml).html(thisFileSizeShort);
```

I have multiple files option set to default, so i will add this code as well:

```
$('form ul.JSpreveiw li:not(:last-child)').slideUp(settings.closeAnimationSpeed,function(){$('form ul.JSpreveiw li:not(:last-child)').remove()});
```

But if you have multiple files set to more then 1 then change this code accordingly.